# Autogenerate method response in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Consider the following snippet of code

```
private MyOutputObject createMyOutputObject(MyInputObject myInputObject) {

}
```

To get rid of Eclipse's "must return a result of type..." compiler error alert, I will then add the following:

```
private MyOutputObject createMyOutputObject(MyInputObject myInputObject) {
    MyOutputObject myOutputObject = null;
    return myOutputObject;
}
```

Is there any way within Eclipse to autogenerate this response creation?

Comment: If you are going to downvote, can you at least provide a comment

Comment: It's not an eclipse error it is an compiler error...

Comment: I know it's not an error, it's a compiler error alert

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse if you go to Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates you will see a list of code templates. Under Code go to Method body and you can modify the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quick fix in eclipse which will put the `return null` statement.